# Loading gif image is not showing in IE and chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I am using JQuery ajax call for sending synchronized call to server and want to display a loading image for that time.

But loading image is visible in Firefox but not in IE and chrome. When i debug, i found that in IE, when we call java script, it stop showing changes in browser as it halts DOM and when the call is completed, it then shows all the changes. Since i shows the loading image on ajax call and remove it after completing the call, the IE doe not display any image.

But when i use alert box,it shows the loading image in IE as it stop the thread until we response to it.

Is there any method to stop java script execution for a millisecond such that IE execution halts and loading image is shown.

I already tried ajaxSend, ajaxComplete, ajaxStart, ajaxStop of JQuery and timer event of java script, but does not get any solution.

Any help is precious, thanks in advance.

Comment: I've gotten around this problem in IE in the past by putting the Ajax call in a `setTimeout()` with a 1ms delay. Generally then IE will update the page before calling the timeout callback that kicks off the Ajax request. Note that if the loading image isn't already in the browser cache it may not load in time to display before the Ajax response comes back.

Comment: I tried setTimeout() but its not working.

Comment: Just as much as you can replicate the problem. It doesn't have to have any logic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the context of XHR, *synchronously* means just that the browser freezes until the request is complete. If what you want is to make sure only one request is running at a given time, then use your own flag to indicate that a request is in progress.

By definition, the synchronous flag of a request means that any other activity must stop. I'm surprised that it even works in Firefox, last time I tried that it didn't work, but that was a long time ago. So forget about it, there's no way to make it work in all browsers. Even if you delay the request using a `setTimeout`, at best you'll get a frozen browser with a non-animated gif. And users don't like when you freeze their browser, especially if the request might take more than a fraction of a second.

**Don't ever depend on the browser for security or correct functionality related features.** If your application might get broken if a client does two requests in parallel, then you have a bug on the server side. There's nothing that prevents a malicious user from making parallel requests using other tools than the normal UI.

Comment: setTimeout is a workaround that at least allows you to display some message. When doing calls to some AJAX API and you need them to be in a specific order synchronous calls are the easy way. Using complex callbacks is also an option, but it can get messy.

Answer (score 4):

You problem is probably the 'synchronized' part in your opening post.

Open the connection asynchronously. That stops the browser from locking up, and it will work as you expect. (set async = true on your XmlHttpRequest / activex object)

Answer (score 1):

try to shows the loading image at the start of your ajax jquery call and hide it on success event

or

you can use set time out also

Answer (score 1):

I also faced similar problem while working with ajax like i applied some styles to UI during ajax call but these are not applied to UI and same as you told that if we put some alert it will work as expected until OK is not clicked for alert

I can't guess why it happening but you can use JQuery to show or Hide that Loading.... div
Hope it will work....

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and then I sorted it out by using the Update Panel in ASP.NET. If you are using PHP or any other technology then you have to use ajax call. If you do synchronized call then the Loading image will not be shown.

Comment: I am using synchronous call and its necessary. How about web workers. Is there any way to solve this with web workers.

Comment: You can use anything you like but if the page reloads while processing the request then the .gif image will not be shown in IE and chrome. But instead you can show loading text, it should work.

Comment: Whole page does not reload in my case. I am only change the div content, but loading image is not shown during synchronous Ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar situation to deal with, if you have to make the synchronous call, browser will suspend the DOM manipulation. So unless absolutely necessary, keep with the async calls.

There is a workaround for manipulating the DOM and show an element before starting the ajax call. Use jQuery animate(), and make the ajax call in the callback for animation complete. Following code works for me:

```
//show the loading animation div
$('#loading').show();

//call dummy animate on element, call ajax on finish handler
$('#loading').animate({
    opacity: 1
  }, 500, function() {
        //call ajax here
        var dataString = getDataString() + p + '&al=1';
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'GET',
            async: false,
            url: 'uldateList.php',
            data: dataString,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(result){
                //Do something with result
                ...
                //hide loading animation
                $('#loading').hide();
            }
        });
  });
```

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't help in my case.Since, my web application is purely based on JQuery, if i used animate function, then it skips ajax call until animate finishes but doesn't stop JavaScript thread execution, which will create problem in other function.

Comment: @MohitPandey, If you want the dom manipulation to happen synchronously, you can add an option to .animate call and set queue to false. This will force the animation to start immediately, in which you can display the image, and complete can then make ajax call. You could choose the animation time as small as 1. more details on the .animate documentation: http://api.jquery.com/animate/ However, I seriously recommend review the design of the application and make it asynchronous for cleaner code.

Comment: I will try it and then let you know.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to execute the ajax synchronous call in the image load callback.

Something like:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "loading.gif";
img.onload = function() {
    /* ajax synch call */
}
```

Then append img to DOM.

Comment: Since, my web application is purely based on JQuery, if i used onload function, then it skips ajax call until image load but doesn't stop JavaScript thread execution, which will create problem in other function.

Comment: Had you try to use 'beforeSend' callback to show loading image?

Comment: Yes, i already tried it, but its not working in my case for .gif image.

Comment: Did you have preloaded the gif image?

Answer (score 0):

Hi try to modify ajax call like this its works for me

```
    xmlHttp.open('POST', url, true);
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = myHandlerFunction;
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Accept-Charset", "charset=UTF-8");
xmlHttp.send(query);
```

Comment: I am using jquery $.ajax() function.

Comment: see how you can add ("Accept-Charset", "charset=UTF-8") and (Accept-Charset", "charset=UTF-8) to your call only these statements made differencxe for me

Answer (score 0):

I used Sergiu Dumitriu's information as base. I set my async to true and added

```
  beforeSend: function() {
    $('#Waiting').jqmShow();
  },
  complete: function() {
    $('#Waiting').jqmHide();
  }
```

And it worked for me. Basically i created my own async:false attribute.

Answer (score 0):

In your $.ajax call you need to add async: true. Following code works for me:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax_url',
    data: 'sending_data',
    type: 'POST',
    cache : false,
    async: true,
    beforeSend: function() {
        $('#id_of_element_where_loading_needed').html('html_of_loading_gif');
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $('#id_of_element_where_result_will_be_shown').html(data.body);           
    }
});
```